# Modify the Background of the Button in Richfaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I'm trying to change the `backgraund-image` of an element `h:commandButton`. It's inside a `RichFaces:panel`.

I made a css file with the following rule:

```
.sButton
{
     background-image:url('../imgs/btnTexture2.jpg');
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     color: white;
}
```

In the xhtml file

```
<h:commandButton id="btnTest" styleClass="sButton" ...../>
```

It doesn't work with RichFaces, but it works fine with JSF.

When I checked in Chrome, I found the problem is a rule inside the file `skinning.ecss:31`.
How do I avoid that rule?

If I define the `style` attribute in the `commandButton`, it works, but I don't want to put the style in the xhtml file.

How can I force the application of my rule?
How can I modify the background of `h:commanButton` in RichFaces?

Comment: did you put your styleclass definetion under /view/stylesheet/theme.css ?

Comment: No, I created a folder in the same level of the WEB-INF directory, is Necesary to create that Structure? o Where is that?. The problem is that the "style" of RichFaces has more priority than my "style rule". I have read about the "Skinnability" but it's a extensive process cause I have to define all the Parameters Tables and for the moment I only want to change the background, maybe in the future I'll do that

Comment: i think u should create. How can server find your css file ? did you define your css file path somewhere ?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I use the next CSS style input[type="button"].MyClass, like I said the problem is that RichFace's style have more priority that a rule like ".sButton {background-image:url('../imgs/btnTexture2.jpg');}", for that reason, I did a rule with 2 conditions in order to have the more priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I use the next CSS style

```
input[type="button"].sButton
{
     background-image:url('../imgs/btnTexture2.jpg');
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     color: white;
}
```

With that rule the background-image is changed.
I didn't have to use a "styleclass definetion under /view/stylesheet/theme.css"(whatever that means).

like I said the problem is that RichFace's style have more priority that a rule like

```
.sButton
{
     background-image:url('../imgs/btnTexture2.jpg');
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     color: white;
}
```

The files were applied in the next order

```
panel.ecss
skinning.ecss
myStyleFile.css
```

for that reason, I did a rule with 2 conditions in order to have the more priority, with this change the final order was

```
myStyleFile.css
panel.ecss
skinning.ecss
```

It was easier than I had thought.